# Is there a way to activate env in project folder in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I have created a env in my project folder using below code
conda create --prefix /Windows/Analytics/Python/Project_1/test-env python=3.9.12

but later restarting my system, the anaconda pointed to base so I was activating the env using below code but did not happen. Can anyone help me here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/activate+conda+environment+in+bash+script) I think this is the answer of your question.

Comment: nope this link did not help.... The ask is :) how to activate env in my project location...